# iPhone Dev animation of back button not working

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm using *mono touch* and developing the following app. 
`UITabBarController` with 4 `UINavigationControllers`.

The problem occurs after I navigate with the NavigationController and click the back button. It pops but **without** animation. In addition scrolling to the right is not working with the proper animation like we know it from *iOS 7*.

What can cause this?

Answer (score 0):

its because you have

> 4 UINavigationControllers.

The push/pop animations working only in same controller. You should use a view animation like this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        firstView.alpha = 0.0;
        secondView.alpha = 1.0;
}];
```

(visit  [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html) for more info )

or an other custom animation.

Comment: The push animation does work. it's the pop animation that soesn't work. 
And what do you mean by "animation works only in same controller" ? what is the same if you can be more specific. Last, just to make it clear I have a UITabCOntroller in each different index I have a UINavigationController, so I don't see why this should be any difference. it's exactly like instagram structure.